# How to use ServiceStack's ProxyFeature when POST with URL Parameters, but empty body?

Tags: c#, servicestack

I'm working on service using ServiceStack (5.5.0) and ProxyFeature plugin. So this one (let me call it ProxyService) will work as proxy to other services. My problem comes when I'm trying to make proxy request with "POST", URL parameter and an empty body. How can I make this to run?

If I try it with not empty body, e.g. not with URL Parameter, everything is OK.

In one of those services I have something like

```
[Route("/data/changeitem/{Id}", "POST")]
public class ChangeDataItemForId : IItem, IReturnVoid
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{nameof(ChangeDataItemForId)} {Id}";
    }
}
```

in Proxy Service AppHost.Configure

```
        Plugins.Add(new ProxyFeature(
            matchingRequests: req => req.PathInfo.StartsWith("/data", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase),
            resolveUrl: req => MyHost + req.RawUrl));
```

I get the following Error: 
HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length.